# handler for SIGALRM does not work

Tags: c, linux, signals, scheduler

I'm on an Assignment.

The Assignment is making virtual Real Time Operating System on Linux System(on Ubuntu).

My problem is SIGALRM and it's handler for Scheduler.

```
void scheduler(int signo) {
        /*variables */
        printf("Scheduler awake!!\n");
        /* Do
           Schedule */
}

int RunScheduler(void) {
        signal(SIGALRM, scheduler);
        alarm(1);
        while(1)
                pause();
        return 0;
}

int main() {
        RunScheduler();
}
```

The function scheduler(handler) does not work. alarm(1) works, but just paused after alarm(1).

Is there any reason signal handler does not work??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The very same code works correctly on my machine.

I have used the gcc compiler that comes bundled with Ubuntu. Are you using the same compiler?

Comment: Yeap, use gcc with ubuntu

Comment: I think the pause inside the loop might be causing variation in behavior. Try running the code without that pause (since you are anyways within an infinite loop). If that doesn't work, use sigaction instead of signal.

Comment: I got Clear. It's my mistake. The argument of function sleep is defined wrong.